# React Native & TextInput : How to get what the use type one by one for Android?

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, textinput

I'm trying to make this `OTP` (`6 digits`) input boxes in `react native`.
What will happen is - when the user presses any key (except the `backspace` key), it should jump to the next box and when the user presses the `backspace` key, it should go back to the previous box.

So far it works fine with `iOS`, then when I checked on `Android`, it doesn't jump to the next box at all. I checked online and found out that `onKeyPress` is not supported in `Android`. How can I make it work for android without `onKeyPress`? Should I use `onChange`? But then how could I know if the user press on `backspace`?

```
             <TextInput
                editable={editable}
                value={input_1}
                style={styles.inputBox}
                keyboardType='number-pad'
                ref={box_1}
                // onChange={({ text }) => {
                //   setInput_1(text);
                // }}

                onFocus={() => {
                 
                }}
                onKeyPress={({ nativeEvent }) => {
                  if (nativeEvent.key === 'Backspace') {
                    box1.current.focus();
                  } else {
                    focus(1);
                  }
                }}
              />
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the docs say it ***work*** in android but from `soft keyboard` not `hardware keyboard` ***and i think you may ignore hardware keyboard***.

the [docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput#onkeypress) say that

> Note: on Android only the inputs from soft keyboard are handled, not
> the hardware keyboard inputs.

###### What is the different between `soft keyboard` and `hardware keyboard`?

`soft keyboard` (*onscreen keyboard or software keyboard*) like keyboard in the screen of phone or tablet.
`hardware keyboard` (*external keyboard*) like keyboard with USB (android support that).

If you test in emulator, try to use the emulator keyboard by mouse, not computer keyboard.

###### if you can't ignore hardware keyboard

I suggest to use this library [react-native-confirmation-code-field](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-confirmation-code-field) try snack [here](https://snack.expo.io/@retyui/demo-for-react-native-confirmation-code-field?platform=android)

or follow the library way, It uses an invisible  component that will be stretched over  components.

[image]